# Mobile Iron integration with React-native

Tags: react-native, mobileiron

I have React-native application, Now I would like to use AppConnect for my application, what is the best way to achieve it?In old threads(Mobile Iron official) I found we can't use AppConnect for React-Native application, still this features is not available? Please lead to me to the answer

Comment: Have you ever solved this? I'm facing the same for one of our apps now.

Comment: Yes I used swift bridge library to solve this

Comment: Do you have any samples on this? :)